# Excluding everything above denormalized date in query

Tags: mysql, denormalization

I denormalized my data (so a date is split up in a year, month, day and hour column)
But now I wonder how to query everything before a certain date.

This does NOT work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `impression_stat_hour` 
WHERE doneforday =0
AND (
    YEAR <=2011
    AND MONTH <=6
    AND DAY <=30
    AND HOUR <=1
)
```

This won't actually "group" all the records together as I want them too, resulting in date that is (for example) always from hour 0 and hour 1.

Comment: I'm curious, what was your reason for denormalizing the date?

Comment: The approach we use in our application is to store two values, a DATE key and a TIME key. These are FKs to a date and time table. The date table has a single row for every date from Jan 1, 2000, through the end of 2020. We can add more dates when we get close to 2020 :).  And the time table contains a single row for every second of the day.  Then we do a similar query to the one provided in my and Bill Karwin's answers, the only difference is that there are only two columns to compare-not 4 (or 6 if you also track minutes and seconds).

Comment: Our approach doesn't work well if you have a requirement for open-ended dates. But since we're only using our dates for real-time events, it works for us.

Comment: This table contains millions of records, and at first I had a regular datetime field. But then I had to group them by year, month, day and hour and it took way too long for the query to run. With this denormalized data it runs A LOT quicker.

Comment: That's precisely the reason we broke ours up, too... indexing can be a lot more efficient on the smaller fields, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ...
WHERE
    YEAR < 2011
    OR (YEAR = 2011 AND MONTH < 6)
    OR (YEAR = 2011 AND MONTH = 6 AND DAY < 30)
    OR (YEAR = 2011 AND MONTH = 6 AND DAY = 30 AND HOUR <= 1)
```

Or:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(year,'-',month,'-',day,' ',hour,':00:00')) <= '2011-06-30 01:00:00';
```

The latter is probably a lot slower (since it can't use indexes on your various date columns. It's also untested, since the only (ancient) version of MySQL I have access to doesn't support STR_TO_DATE().

Answer (score 1):

1. You'd have to make the condition be more complex to handle ties:

   ```
   AND (YEAR < 2011 OR (YEAR = 2011 
     AND (MONTH < 6 OR (MONTH = 6 
       AND (DAY < 30 OR (DAY = 30 AND HOUR <= 1))))))
   ```
2. It's probably easier to read if you combine the columns back into a `DATETIME` value and then compare that to a specific datetime literal:

   ```
   AND (STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR,'-', MONTH,'-', DAY, ' ', HOUR), 
    '%Y-%m-%d %h') < '2011-06-30 02:00')
   ```
3. You could also store an extra column that is an actual `DATETIME` based on the same value as that of the columns with separate datetime components.  That would allow you to index the datetime column for more efficient lookups.

   ```
   AND (complete_date < '2011-06-30 02:00')
   ```

I just tested this on MySQL 5.5, including the answer from @Flimzy.  The only one that can use an index is my method 3 above, with the redundant column.